# Grouping text chunks and converting them to objects

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using an API which returns a text file that looks something like this:

```
#start
#p 09060 20131010
#p 09180 AK
#p 01001 19110212982
#end
#start
#p 09060 20131110
#p 09180 AB
#p 01001 12110212982
#end
```

I would like to convert the result to a list of objects:

```
[{
    09060: 20131010,
    09180: 'AK',
    01001: 19110212982
},
{
    09060: 20131110,
    09180: 'AB',
    01001: 12110212982
}]
```

I tried to make groups out of each `#start` to `#end` section using regex, without success:

```
unmatched ) in regular expression
text.match(/#start(.*?)#end/)
-----------^
```

I also had `split()` in mind. Perhaps it's more suitable, if there is a way to set a "start" + "end"? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis just before the last slash.

Comment: @M42 Sorry, typo. However, this expression yeilds no results.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on `"#end"` followed by `"#start"`. Just make sure to remove the initial `"#start"` and final `"#end"` first

```
text = text.substr(7, text.length-12)
text.split("#end\n#start")
```